# How do I improve the bottom part of this horse walk cycle animation?

Tags: animation

[image]

So this is a horse walk cycle for a videogame that looks incredibly stiff and mechanical. I know the whole body should engage in the action, but I'd prefer to get the legs right first. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: ***Welcome*** to **GD.SE** - *Please* look through **[tour]** to get a sense of our community – who we are and what we’re about. *Then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes a good query here, *and* how best to frame it. as initially framed, your query is both unclear and very broad - you've not actually asked a question, let alone a scope-limited question as preferred here. FYI - super-broad "help me / do it for me" questions tend to get closed quickly - perhaps you could edit it to narrow to a clearly addressable question?

Comment: And a quick thought on the animation for myself is that the spine is totally inactive - and in all quadrupeds, there's a series of compression and expansion and wave forms involved in locomotion, both due to the local rotation near joints and due to energy storage and release; attendant with the motion of the larger portion of spine between the leg pairs, the head should bob in opposition to the flexing of the back - and you probably want both squoosh and anticipation / overmotion to communicate the living quality of the animation subject. I'll leave actual answers to better qualified folks.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, both on the animation and the question itself. I'll do what I can to improve on them, though i can't promise perfection.

Comment: Have you looked for other examples of a horse walking? There are lots on the internet. Here's [one](http://cdn-ak.f.st-hatena.com/images/fotolife/R/Rosylife/20151211/20151211194240.gif). I'm not saying you should copy it, but it should give you an idea of what to aim for.

Comment: You could take a look at Eadweard Muybridge's recordings from the late 1800's. There are some galloping horses on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eadweard_Muybridge), but I'm sure I've seen a walking horse somewhere too.

Comment: Nice job improving your question in response to comments - thank you! You'll also notice you get better responses this way!

Answer (score 5):

*As a whole* we *try* to avoid link-based answers here due to the ever-present risks of link-rot, and to keep more actual content here where it can be indexed and thus be available for future searchers - that said, the You Tube video to which I've linked below is ***so*** specifically a nice overall tutorial aimed at hand-drawn animation of a typical horse walk cycle, and is extremely well done, thorough, and easily accessible - that is, the learning curve isn't too steep and it makes sense for beginning animators - that it's an ideal answer for your question.

[Detailed You Tube hand animation Horse Walk cycle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INQx-Lzs8mU)

And here are some representative chunks from that video to show *why* I think it's ideal for your question:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also consider this classic set of source images, as suggested by others:

[image]

**NOTE:** I think it's not possible to *just* consider the feet and end up with a natural flowing motion - you ***need*** a fully engaged spine to make this read as horse-like motion.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Search for real-life examples and take it from there.** Learn how things should move first. Look at how animals behave. In your case, search for [Horse Gait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horse_gait).
2. **Look at the work of others.** How did other animators solve the same problem? [There are so many examples](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=horse%20gait%20animation&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images).
3. It doesn't hurt to also **learn the [12 principles of animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_basic_principles_of_animation)** introduced by Disney's works from the 30's. It's very basic and it helps a lot with creating more realistic animations.